# C++ file parse number of arguments

Tags: c++, parsing, numbers, param

I got a pack of c++ files with static source code (already developped, not needed to do anything to them).

There is an program/lib/way to get a list of the number of params each function withing one of those files?

I mean, getting a result like:

```
#File a.cpp
##a() -> 3 paramss
##foo() -> 0 params (void)

#File b.cpp
##test() -> 1 param

....
```

And a better question.

There is any way to also process the number of returns it has?

```
#File a.cpp
##a() -> 3 params, 1 return
##foo() -> 0 params (void), 2 returns
```

For example if "foo" has a return if condition is true and another if false

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide an example of `foo()` such that it has 2 returns?

Comment: int foo() { if(blah)return 1; else return 0; }

Comment: how do you get 2 returns in c++?

Comment: @MattJoiner I think he wants the number of return statements in the function, not a function returning multiple values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) over the source files.

Since the content is (presumably) undocumented, you need to [configure](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html#extract_all) doxygen to extract content from undocumented files.

If you just want to browse a list of the available functions, you could use the HTML output.

You could also configure Doxygen output to be XML, and then write a parser to pull statistics that you are looking for on each function.

Comment: Doxygen worked well, generating the XML & HTML files.

I only need to parse the xmll then hehe;)

Answer (score 0):

I would count the number of "," and start at 1.  This should give you an accurate count of the number of arguments to a function.  Then I would check to see if "void" exists before the function name, if not then you can bet that there is a return value.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open(...);
int i, ret, args;
String s;

ret = args = 0;
s = infile.getline();
for( i=0; s[i] != '('; i++ ) {
 if( s[i] == 'v' && s[i+1] == 'o' && s[i+2] == 'i' && s[i+3] == 'd' ) {
  ret = 1;
  break;
 }
}

for( i=0; s[i] != '('; i++ ) {}

for( i; s[i] != ')'; i++ ) {
 if( args == 0 && s[i] != ' ' ) {
  args++;
 }
 if( s[i] == ',' ) {
  args++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Counting commas would fail on things such as template<class A, class B> void doSomething(const SomeClass<A,B> &thingy, const std::string &other);

Comment: You are correct, counting comma's would fail with Templates in c++; the easier way to do it would be to write a regular expression to do it.

Comment: Code has templates (and lots of em), so i couldnt do this hehe

Answer (score 0):

All this is way over the top but maybe this might be your cup of tea, [Elsa](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~smcpeak/elkhound/sources/elsa/) can parse c++ and provide you with an abstract syntax tree of the parsed file. There might be some other free tools out there that can do the same

Comment: i may try this when i get the dependencies hehe